# listview with upcoming NOTIFICATION texts and images from whatsapp

Tags: android, image, listview, text, notifications

I'm a new developer on Android, and I'm trying to feed a `ListView` with notifications (texts and image). I've already done the text, but I'm not achieving to do with upcoming images notifications.
I've tried with bitmaps and byte arrays, but still not done yet.

This is my code

```
public class NotificationService extends NotificationListenerService {
    Context context;

    @Override

    public void onCreate() {

        super.onCreate();
        context = getApplicationContext();

    }
    @Override

    public void onNotificationPosted(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        String pack = sbn.getPackageName();
        String ticker ="";
        if(sbn.getNotification().tickerText !=null) {
            ticker = sbn.getNotification().tickerText.toString();
        }
        Bitmap bmp = null;
        Bundle extras = sbn.getNotification().extras;
        if (extras.containsKey(Notification.EXTRA_PICTURE)) {

            bmp = (Bitmap) extras.get(Notification.EXTRA_PICTURE);


        }
        String title = extras.getString("android.title");
        String text = null;
        if (text == null) {
            if (extras.get("android.textLines") != null) {
                CharSequence[] charText = (CharSequence[]) extras
                        .get("android.textLines");
                if (charText.length > 0) {
                    text = charText[charText.length - 1].toString();
                }
            }
        }
        int id1 = extras.getInt(Notification.EXTRA_SMALL_ICON);

        Bitmap id = sbn.getNotification().largeIcon;



        Log.i("Ticker",ticker);
        Log.i("Title",title);
        Log.i("Text",text);



        Intent msgrcv = new Intent("Msg");
        msgrcv.putExtra("package", pack);
        msgrcv.putExtra("ticker", ticker);
        msgrcv.putExtra("title", title);
        msgrcv.putExtra("text", text);
        msgrcv.putExtra("byteArray",bmp);




        if(id != null) {
            ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            id.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
            byte [] byteArray = stream.toByteArray();
            msgrcv.putExtra("icon",byteArray);
        }
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(msgrcv);


    }

    @Override

    public void onNotificationRemoved(StatusBarNotification sbn) {
        Log.i("Msg","Notification Removed");

    }
}
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted the code you're working with. And please also review this article: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: ok, i've already posted the code that i'm using for read notifications! thanks for the advice.